# How can I cast a spanish date (14-ENE-2021) in a single spark sql query?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a file with dates that are imported as strings with the following format:

`14-ENE-2021`

as a spanish date (ene = january). I need to cast this as a date in a single spark SQL query. So far I have tried:

`spark.sql("select TO_DATE('14-ENE-21', 'dd-MMM-yy')").show()`

Which returns null.

Answer (score 0):

It's a tricky one, but you can use `from_csv` to set a locale:

```
spark.sql("""
    select from_csv(
        '14-ENE-21',
        'date date',
        map('dateFormat', 'dd-MMM-yy', 'locale', 'ES')
    ).date as date
""").show()
+----------+
|      date|
+----------+
|2021-01-14|
+----------+
```

(inspired from [the docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html))

Comment: I'm sorry I meant I can't execute this query, I get the following error: `Undefined function: 'from_csv'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database`

Comment: What I mean by a single query is I have access only to the "SELECT" part of the query and the rest is handle in bulk (we have a set of parameteres already established which I can't change)

Comment: `from_csv` is only available since Spark 3.0. I'm not sure if there's any other neater way to solve this, but you can consider translating the Spanish months to English using `replace`.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a custom `toDate` UDF like this:

```scala
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Locale

spark.udf.register("toDate", (value: String, pattern: String, locale: String) => {
    try {
      val parser = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, new Locale(locale))
      val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US)
      Some(new java.sql.Date(parser.parse(value.trim).getTime))
    } catch {
      case _: Exception => None
    }
  }
)

spark.sql("select toDate('14-ENE-21', 'dd-MMM-yy', 'ES') as date").show()

//+----------+
//|      date|
//+----------+
//|2021-01-14|
//+----------+
```

Comment: How can I do this in Pyspark do I have to compile and add the Jar to pyspark